# How to create a mirror link in an email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, html

I'm creating email template with Marketing Cloud tool. I upload the html of my email directly, we do not use template.

I'd like to create a "mirror link" or "view the email as web page" link. What do i need to put in my "href" inside my html ?

Comment: Hello @Julien, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help), scroll through the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You can get better support if you can try to elaborate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [**Personalization Strings**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/) page in the documentation.

The `%%view_email_url%%` one is what you want.  You use it like this:

```
<a href="%%view_email_url%%" alias="vawp">view as a web page</a>
```